# App crashes when trying to open a fragment

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments, android-activity

I am trying to open a fragment from an activity using

```
   buttonreturn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Chapter1Activity.this, Chapter1.class);
            startActivity(intent);
```

Chapter1 is the fragment that i am trying to access
but whenever i press the button that makes it open, the app crashes.
any ideas?

EDIT

logcat:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.boszcorp.revappbiology/com.boszcorp.revappbiology.FooFragment}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.boszcorp.revappbiology.FooFragment cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2240)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2391)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:147)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1296)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5256)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:898)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.boszcorp.revappbiology.FooFragment cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1065)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2391)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:147)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1296)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5256)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:898)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
```

Comment: Look for messages in LogCat.  If you understand them, problem solved.  If you don't under stand them edit your question to include the LogCat output.

Comment: an idea could come if You post Your logcat...

Comment: You haven't to use Intent to pass from activity to fragment but FragmentManager and FragmentTransaction

Comment: You won't be able to start a fragment directly from an intent. Use a fragment manager or either call an activity that includes this particular fragment.

Answer (score 1):

As the use of fragment is wrong. It should be like this

```
    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    Fragment newFragment = MyFragment.newInstance("From Arguments");
    ft.add(R.id.created, newFragment);
    ft.commit();
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html